# Load API JSON data in table

Tags: json, html-table

I am an old Greek Pharmacist and my hobby is web development.
So, I have this URL
https://clinicaltrials.gov/api/query/study_fields?expr=lansoprazole&fields=NCTId%2CBriefTitle%2CCondition&min_rnk=1&max_rnk=10&fmt=json
and I want to have all its JSON data in an html table.
I tried with Fetch API, but I did not succeed :(
How can this be done with JavaScript or PHP?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$jsondump = file_get_contents('https://clinicaltrials.gov/api/query/study_fields?expr=lansoprazole&fields=NCTId%2CBriefTitle%2CCondition&min_rnk=1&max_rnk=50&fmt=json');
// Decode JSON data to PHP associative array
$data = json_decode($jsondump, true);

if($data['StudyFieldsResponse']['MaxRank'] <= $data['StudyFieldsResponse']['NStudiesFound'])
{
  $keynum=$data['StudyFieldsResponse']['MaxRank'];
}
else
{
  $keynum=$data['StudyFieldsResponse']['NStudiesFound'];
}
echo ("NStudiesReturned: ") . $keynum;
echo "<hr><br>";
?>

<table border=1 width=800>
<tr><td>Rank</td><td>NCTId</td><td>BriefTitle</td><td>Condition</td></tr>

<?php
$x=0;
while ($x <= $keynum-1){
$rank = $data['StudyFieldsResponse']['StudyFields'][$x]['Rank'];
$nctid=$data['StudyFieldsResponse']['StudyFields'][$x]['NCTId'][0];
$title = $data['StudyFieldsResponse']['StudyFields'][$x]['BriefTitle'][0];
$condition_count=count($data['StudyFieldsResponse']['StudyFields'][$x]['Condition']);
//echo $condition_count;


 
echo "<tr><td> $rank</td><td>$nctid</td><td>$title</td><td><b>";
$ccx=0;
while ($ccx <= $condition_count-1){
$condition = $data['StudyFieldsResponse']['StudyFields'][$x]['Condition'][$ccx];
echo "<p>$condition</p>";
$ccx++;
}
echo "</b></td></tr>";

$x++;
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).